# Problems with Virtual environments and packages (python)

Tags: python

Im working in python in vscode, I have created a virtual environment  and installed all the packages I need to it, I selected the interpreter, but running the code still gives me the error no module named
`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html_text = requests.get('https://www.timesjobs.com/candidate/job-search.html?searchType=personalizedSearch&from=submit&txtKeywords=python&txtLocation=').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find('li', class_ = 'clearfix job-bx wht-shd-bx')
for job in jobs:
    company_name = job.find('h3', class_ = 'joblist-comp-name').text.replace(' ','')
    skills = job.find('span', class_ = "srp-skills").text.replace(' ', '')

    published_date = job.find('span', class_ = 'sim-posted').span.text
    
    print(f'''
    Company Name: {company_name}
    Required Skills: {skills}
    ''')

    print('')
```

`
those are the libraries another weird things is I can install them outside the virtual environment and select  the .venv interpreter and it will run the code like I have the libraries installed even though the virtual environment interpreter is selected. I was just following a free code camp tutorial on Beautiful Soup. Any help would be appreciated.

another weird things is I can install them outside the virtual environment and select  the .venv interpreter and it will run the code like I have the libraries installed even though the virtual environment interpreter is selected, I tried selecting the path to the interpreter myself and it still didn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled the packages and its still says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\{my user}\Desktop\Code\webscraper.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I also made sure that the packages are in the .venv folder
[image: file explorer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate the virtualenv, and then install BeautifulSoup4:

```
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

or,

```
pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Comment: wdym by activate the environment, I have already installed the packages into the environment. Sorry I'm very new to python.

Comment: If you have already installed the packages into the global environment then it should work.

Comment: Hey man, You may be new but it's not a problem. Just keep patience. Could you please write a command `pip list` in your terminal? then check whether the package is installed or not.

Comment: it shows the packages in the list of installed ones,
 
Package            Version
------------------ -----------
aiohttp            3.8.1
aiosignal          1.2.0
async-timeout      4.0.2
attrs              22.1.0
beautifulsoup4     4.11.1
certifi            2022.9.24
charset-normalizer 2.1.1
frozenlist         1.3.1
idna               3.4
lxml               4.9.1
multidict          6.0.2
pip                22.3.1
py-cord            2.0.0
requests           2.28.1
setuptools         63.2.0
soupsieve          2.3.2.post1
urllib3            1.26.12
yarl               1.8.1

Comment: Sorry, Forgot to say that I ran that command in the virtual environment, they were not installed in the global one, but from my understanding the whole point of virtual environments is that you don't have to install it to the global environment.

Comment: Just follow the process correctly: 
`create venv -> activate venv -> intall packageg`